# Serverless API Gateway on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, gcp-load-balancer, google-cloud-api-gateway, identity-aware-proxy

I'm looking for a solution to have a gateway to serverless on GCP with an Authorization/ Authentication made by IAM but didn't find a perfect solution to it.

The idea's to have these gateway managing endpoints from APIs on GCP Functions, Cloud Run and App Engine using `Bearer $TOKEN` generated by `gcloud auth print-identity-token` command. Also, needed an IAP integration to manage access by allowing a Gmail domain like, allow access to all `@company.com` users.

First I tried API Gateway but it's not possible to invoke the endpoints without a signed token with SA private key and also don't have IAP integration. Then, I tried HTTPS Load Balancer and successfully got programmatic access but not IAP since it doesn't have integration with Cloud Functions.

Is there another possibility or the next step it's to try to do this API Gateway using Kong or Nginx?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want with Cloud Run.

Cloud Run can be [protected by IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run). In addition, you can deploy [ESPv2 on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run) (ESPv2 is the open source version of API Gateway)

I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) on ESPv2 on Cloud Run, if you need details and code sample

Comment: I'll defitely give it a try on that. Thanks for your answer